# AndroidAnnotations and Dagger

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-annotations, dagger

I'm trying to use Dagger to inject into an android Annotated Activity.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.app.server.AddServerActivity_. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.`

If I try and Add the `com.app.server.AddServerActivity_` to the module I get a diffrent error

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:276)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1018)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:742)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:790)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:705)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:314)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:179)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:220)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Class
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$ValueVisitor.visitArray(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Array.accept(Attribute.java:215)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$ValueVisitor.getValue(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:165)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker.generateValue(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:143)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker.getAllReflectedValues(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker.generateAnnotation(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker.generateAnnotation(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:78)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements.getAnnotation(JavacElements.java:108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements.getAnnotation(JavacElements.java:121)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.getAnnotation(Symbol.java:888)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ValidationProcessor.validateProvides(ValidationProcessor.java:75)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 24 more
```

Edit: ok, it seems to be a known issue with how dagger deals with classes generated by other processors.

https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/322

Comment: Now you can use Dagger in the latest SNAPSHOT of AndroidAnnotations, we copy all annotations to the generated classes.

Comment: I seem to be unable to find the latest snapshot on maven.org or via google search. Could you point it out to me of where I can get that snapshot build?

Comment: @imgen [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/androidannotations/). But we already released a stable version with that copy feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger), whose usage seems more "natural".

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/322) was fixed as of commit [709a48b](https://github.com/cgruber/dagger/commit/709a48b82ad35396a46f93ece101224f8dcd71b0) of Dagger.

> Collaborator cgruber commented Nov 13, 2013
>
> This has been validated in two places, so I'm closing this issue.

Still, using Dagger2, which is a joint effort of google and square, seems a good idea.